# Issues SQL connection with a specific account

Tags: google-cloud-sql, google-app-maker

I'm having an issue with the CloudSQL connection on a specific account. 
If I use account A to preview the project it works fine, yet account B with the exact same cloudSQL credentials is unable to preview, account B is the owner of the project.

[image]

They both have the same IAM roles in the cloudSQL project and both accounts were able to preview last week. 
I've tried deleting cache, navigation files and another browser using account B.

Any ideas?

Comment: I have seen something similar before and it was fixed by re-updating the Cloud SQL settings in App Maker using account B. Go to Settings (gear icon) > GOOGLE CLOUD SQL > Try updating all three options (change, check, update) and see it that helps. Also I suggest that you try previewing the app with a 3rd user and see if the issue persist since that might help to isolate the issue. If persistent, then it will be better to contact G Suite Support to report this problem.

Comment: It's specifically with the owner account, I've tried severl times now to change the SQL string and all, just to try to "reboot it" but the problem remains. Hope Taylor can help me out on this one, cause I agree it seems like an odd bug.
Accont A is able for example to check inside AppMakers UI, its only on the preview or deploy that the sql credentials arent valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to add a new answer to resolve this because I think it's worthwhile to keep the previous answer and discussion intact. The issue here was that the accounts which did not work have the "Viewer" role in the IAM & Admin section of the Google Cloud SQL project. The Viewer role gives (among other permissions) read access to Cloud SQL, but not write access.

The best role to use if restricted access is required, but they need full access to read/write SQL, is the Google Cloud SQL Client role. See https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/project-access-control for more information on roles and what access they give.

Thanks for Juan for help tracking all this down.

Edit: It's also worth mentioning that the reason this works in the Editor, but not in Preview/Deployments is the editor is explicitly whitelisted for access (as one of the steps we ask you to do in the documentation), so it doesn't use role permissions for a particular account, while access through your deployments is not explicitly whitelisted in this way, so role permissions are enforced.

Answer (score 0):

Do the following, in Incognito windows in Chrome (to make sure you're using the correct account):

1) Log into the account it is not working with.
2) In the Google Cloud SQL tab, press Update, and enter new credentials, wait for it to finish, and then try to preview.
3) Assuming this does not work, now close your incognito window and log into the account it is working with. 
4) Repeat step #2 (entering new the same credentials).

If you cannot access it after step #2, but you can access on step #4, and if both users can modify the SQL model from App Maker, then there is a probably strange bug we (the App Maker team) needs to look into.

Comment: Thanks Devin, will try first thing on Monday !  I'll keep you posted

Comment: Hey Devin. 
It's exactly as you mentioned. I can access after step #4 (usual working account) but not after step #2, they can both modifiy the model (import models, etc). 
Also with the broken account we created an export project and we have the exact same issue, it seems something to do with the project and the owner account. 

Should I email you directly?

Comment: Sure, send me a mail and I'll follow up there. Sure sounds like a bug. One more thing to try would be creating a new application with the account that does not work, and seeing if preview works for the new app.

Comment: Just tried, same issue. I'll send you an email thanks!